# Embedding IE window inside a QFrame

Tags: c++, qt, internet-explorer, qtgui, qobject

I'm trying to embed an IE window into a `QFrame` using `QProcess` to call the IE application. I'm working on Win7 32bit using Qt 5.2.1.

I have tried the following approaches

- Try to set the parent of the process to be the frame, instead of the MainWindow by this

  ```
  QProcess *process = new QProcess(ui->frame_Video);
  ```

AND by this

```
QProcess *process = new QProcess(ui->frame_Video); 
process->setParent(ui->frame_Video);
```

Then I tried to use the `QWidget::createWindowContainer()` method. This is the workflow I tried to follow:

Get the WId of the IE window (by using the hWnd of the IE window or another method)
Use the `QWindow::fromWinID()` to create a `Qwindow`
Pass the `QWindow` into `QWidget::createWindowContainer()`

My Questions:

1. Is it possible to embed an IE window into a Qt application?
2. With regards to my first method, how can I make a QFrame object a parent object of a QProcess
3. Is the third method valid? (I still need to find how to convert the hWnd into a WId)

Comment: I don't think `QProcess` implements anything for embedding. It runs a separate process (application) from your Qt application. You may try to look at `QAxWidget` instead.

Comment: Can an application (like IE) be run as an ActiveX control object?

Comment: @user3079474 Yes, and that's what you want to do, and you should be using the activeqt module for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers to my question

Yes, It is possible to embed an IE window into a Qt application, (as pointed out by @vahancho ) You will have to use QAxWidgets. See the web browser example in Examples/Activeqt for more details